# Preserve the CDATA Tag after parse using XMLEvent

Tags: xml, cdata, saxparser

Im using `XMLEvent` and its imposible to detect the CDATA part. I mean if im triying `event.asCharacters().isCData()` always is false.

I have to parse an entire XML and escape all characters except the entire CDATA block. I need this to be exactly the same in the ouput.xml as it is in the input.xml I need to keep the CDATA blocks, with their start and element tags.

My input xml :

```
<Document>
    <FIToFIPmtStsRpt>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>UNKNOWN</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>UNKNOWN</CreDtTm>
        </GrpHdr>
        <OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
            <OrgnlMsgId>UNKNOWN</OrgnlMsgId>
            <OrgnlMsgNmId>UNKNOWN</OrgnlMsgNmId>
            <GrpSts>UNKNOWN</GrpSts>
            <StsRsnInf>
                <Rsn>
                    <Prtry>UNKNOWN</Prtry>
                </Rsn>
                <AddtlInf>
                        <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" ?><RequestPayload><h:AppHdr xmlns:h="UNKNOWN">]]></AddtlInf>
                <AddtlInf>
                        <![CDATA[<h:Fr><h:FIId><h:FinInstnId><h:BICFI>UNKNOWN</h:BICFI>    </h:FinInstnId>   </h:FIId>  </h:Fr><h:To><]]></AddtlInf>
            </StsRsnInf>
        </OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
    </FIToFIPmtStsRpt>
</Document>
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Is there a reason why you *need* to preserve the CDATA blocks? If you were to parse the XML, manipulate what you need, and then it happens to serialize as escaped markup instead of having CDATA blocks, that *shouldn't* matter to a downstream consumer, if they parse the XML properly with XML tools. If you are trying to preserve to avoid diffs for version control or something, maybe, but normally when people care about CDATA it's because they are attempting to do string parsing instead of using XML aware tools and APIs.